# Execute a PHP CGI script as a background process?

Tags: php

Can I run a PHP CGI script as a background process using exec() ?

Comment: How 'background' should it be? Asynchronous to the script? And under which operating system?

Comment: Running CGI in the background doesn't really make much sense. The CGI process has to run in the web server's foreground in order for any data to be sent to the client.

Comment: Plus, when running as CGI, the script is (or should be) subject to `max_execution_time` constraints which will prevent any long term running... You should really clarify what you need this for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it to start it as an linux background process using exec().

You could try this:

`exec('/usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php &')`;

The '&' tell's linux to start this command in the background.

Note: You lose control over your executed script at that point and it may not work with all hosts (especially shared host envoirements).